# Magento Training needed for Version 1.9 to Create a Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-theme

I am looking for accelerated online training to be able to `create a theme /package in version 1.9`.

I already have a responsive HTML design, and I can develop in quite a few different languages - but I am not overly familiar with the Magento framework ( I have done bits and pieces with version 1.3 - and I know the basic structure. )

I looked at U Magento - but I find it a bit confusing and more focused on version 2 ( and not sure which ones to take exactly).

I definitely need `Magento v.1.x` as I have quite a few extensions that have a lifetime upgrade for version 1 and payment gateways etc are not available for v. 2.

I would prefer video-based, although a concise step by step guide to get a theme up and running would be really great.

thanks for your time, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For complete theme creation in Magento v-1.9.x you can follow link 2 in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new or child theme we must understand the theme fall back rule of Magento.

How fallback works in Magento 1.9.x ?

[image: Magento theme fallback]

source : [source](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/depth-look-magento-theme-fallback)

Some helpful links:

1) [Creating a new Theme in Magento 1.9](https://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes/)

2) [Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html)

Once you created minimum required folders and fils,set your Package and Theme at `Admin > System > Configuration > Design`